# How to change the field name by using existing header row name of the table; Google BigQuery platform

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sandbox, field-names, header-row

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFDWT.png)my dataset are from google drive in csv format, already uploaded into BigQuery. (sandbox version)

and I found out that the existing header row are not detected automatically. also the table have null row as gap/space and table information note. the existing header row is still in the table but have misplaced at different row automatically.

then preview mode shows that they are using string_field_0, string_field_1, string_field_2, ... as field names.

my goal is how can I change the field name by using the existing header row of the table?

I have tried upload with tick / untick auto-detect box function during the uploading process. the result does not help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: after upload the dataset into BigQuery, the existing column header (known as field name in bigquery) are change into string_field_0, string_field_1, string_field_2, string_field_3, string_field_4, string_field_5 instead of the original one. how can I change it to the original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeahh, I already found out the way how to ensure the existing column header detected and being there as field name.

acknowledge that this situation is table have null row before the header row. so we need to know at what row the header row is located.

the solution is during upload process, the last one before hit button create. go to advanced option and enter number of row where the header row is located.

then tadaa, the header row is used as field name.